# Athena presto query of map type columns with dynamic key names

Tags: sql, apache-spark, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I'm using Athena presto query to find value from a map type column. I want to find a key/value pair with dynamic key names. Specifically, my keys would be like this abc_1, abc_2, ...., abc_100 and it always starts with a perfix, then a dynamic part and finished with some letters. There are many possible combinations and I cannot enumerate all of them. So I'm wondering whether I could use regular expression or wildcard in the keys like something below:

```
selelct map_var1['abc_**'] from tab1.
```

I tagged hive and spark as well and please suggest solutions in other language too. I could use other languages.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map_filter`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/map.html#map_filter):

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(id, map_col) as
    (values (1, map(array['abc_1', 'abc_2', 'skip'], array[1, 2, 3])))

-- query
select map_filter(map_col, (k, v) -> k like 'abc_%')
from dataset;
```

Output:

```
       _col0
--------------------
 {abc_1=1, abc_2=2}
```